# Optaplanner: Dynamically choose between hard/soft constraint?

Tags: dynamic, constraints, optaplanner

I know that you can insert a weight for each constraint dynamically, but is it possible to make the user be in charge of if a rule is adding points to hardConstraintMatch or softConstraintMatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible:

```
rule foo
when
   MyParametrization($fooIsHard : fooIsHard)
   ... // actual pattern
then
   if ($fooIsHard) {
       scoreHolder.addHard...(...);
   } else {
       scoreHolder.addSoft...(...);
   }
end
```